# Connect to a hidden wifi network using task scheduler on Win 10

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-10, task-scheduler

I'm using Lenovo laptop. When I start my session it does not reconnect to a known hidden wireless network. Is it possible to program reconnection via task scheduler?

Answer (score 0):

The way I've always done it is this:

1. While connected to the network go to start and type `cmd` then hit enter
2. In command prompt type `netsh wlan show profile` and find the network you are trying to work with
3. open the start menu and type `regedit` and hit enter
4. in regedit navigate to `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run registry key`
5. Add a string and call it what ever you want (I normally call it logonwifi)
   and set the value to `%comspec% /c netsh wlan connect name="<profile name>"` replacing  with the network profile you want to use
6. reboot and it should automatically connect to the network at startup